# Extra argument 'error' in call in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps

I am new to swift so please treat me as beginner.
I am following [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/), this is pretty old tutorial and it has used GoogleMap framework whereas I am doing it with pod. In `func geocodeAddress` in `MapTasks.swift` file I am getting error called

> Extra argument 'error' in call

```
 func geocodeAddress(address: String!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {
    if let lookupAddress = address {
        var geocodeURLString = baseURLGeocode + "address=" + lookupAddress
        geocodeURLString = geocodeURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let geocodeURL = NSURL(string: geocodeURLString)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let geocodingResultsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: geocodeURL!)

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: geocodingResultsData)

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (let data, let response, let error) in

                if let _ = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                    do {
                        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                        if error != nil {
                            print("error=\(error!)")
                            return
                        }

                        if let parseJSON = json {


                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            else {
                // Get the response status.
                let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

                if status == "OK" {
                    let allResults = dictionary["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
                    self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

                    // Keep the most important values.
                    self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as! String
                    let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                    self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
                    self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

                    completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: "No valid address.", success: false)
    }
}
```

So far I know is I am getting this error because of the diffrent version of swift. Tutorial I am following is written in old version of swift and I am doing it in new

[image]

Comment: you are not associating the variable 'error' with the method. You are simply declaring the variable inside the method. It won't work. Try removing the line "var error?". If it doesnt work and you are qorking with Swift 2.0, then you will need to use do-try-catch method on NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 2.0, you cannot add 'error' argument in NSJSONSerialization method, you need to use try-catch statement as follows:

```
func geocodeAddress(address: String!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {

if let lookupAddress = address {
    var geocodeURLString = baseURLGeocode + "address=" + lookupAddress
    geocodeURLString = geocodeURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let geocodeURL = NSURL(string: geocodeURLString)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let geocodingResultsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: geocodeURL!)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: geocodeURL!)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (let data, let response, let error) in

            if let _ = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                do {
                    let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error!)")
                        return
                    }

                    if let parseJSON = dictionary {
                        let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

                        if status == "OK" {
                            let allResults = dictionary["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
                            self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

                            // Keep the most important values.
                            self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as! String
                            let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                            self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
                            self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

                            completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
                        }
                        else {
                            completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                        }

                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
            task.resume()
        })
        }
```

}

Comment: I am not able to follow your suggestion. What part of My code should I change with your code to make it work? Sorry but I am Beginner to Swift.

Comment: remove "var error?" line and also remove "let dictionary...." method and replace it with the code that I have given.

Comment: When I am trying that, it gives me lot of other errors

Comment: what errors, tell me. They could be because of an extra brace or a lack of a braces. Check braces, or tell me the errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117875/discussion-between-chintan-panchal-and-karanveer-singh).